# RubyMine on Mac, Rails environment on Ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubymine

I have installed RubyMine on Mac but my development environment for Ruby and Rails is on an Ubuntu VPS.

When I run IRB in RubyMine, I assume it is using my Mac environment's IRB?

Cause I have installed rvm, bundler, gems etc in my Ubuntu VPS.

Is it possible to create an application in my Ubuntu VPS and use that environment rather than Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, running the Ruby console from RubyMine uses your Mac's Ruby environment. At the moment it is not possible to launch processes (either irb or your application) on a different host from the one in which RubyMine is running.

Note that bundler should allow you to install the same set of gems on your Mac very easily, so you can have the environment configured both on the Mac and on the Ubuntu VPS.